# Python error 16.06.05or: invalid literal for float(): 28.6521

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import scipy.stats.stats 
import datetime
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats.stats 
import pearsonr

file= u"C:/Users/Nikita/Desktop/file.csv"
with open(file) as f:
 rows = [line.strip().split(';') for line in f][:2482]

dates = [row[0] for row in rows]
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%d.%m.%y") for d in dates] 
dol = [float(row[1]) for row in rows]
val = [float(row[2]) for row in rows]
plt.plot_date(dates, val, fmt='b-')
plt.plot_date(dates, dol, fmt='r-')
plt.figure()
plt.show()

win=1000
depen = []
for i in range(len(val)):
 lo=max(0, i-win)
 hi=min(len(val)-1, i+win)
 depen.append(scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr(val[i-win:i+win], dol[i-win:i+win])[0])
print (depen)
plt.plot_date(dates, depen, fmt='r-')
plt.figure()
ply.show() 

addepend = pearsonr(val, dol)[0]
print (addepend)
print (numpy.corrcoef(val, dol)[0, 1])
```

and use this table:

```
15.06.05    10566.37      28.6521
16.06.05    10578.65      28.6275
17.06.05    10623.07      28.6024
18.06.05    10609.11      28.5841
21.06.05    10599.67      28.4765
22.06.05    10587.93      28.5497
23.06.05    10421.44      28.5528
etc.
```

What is wrong?

```
Error: 16.06.05or: invalid literal for float(): 28.6521
```

Comment: That's a weird-looking error - is this a line ending problem? Try `with open(file, 'rb') as f`.

Comment: Looks like the string it's trying to convert is actually "28.6521\r16.06.05". It's not entirely obvious from the error message because the "\r" causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line and overwrite the existing characters. (I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't know exactly what's causing the issue or how to fix it.)

Comment: The error is being caused when it's going from the first line to the second line. Have you tried using `split(' ')`?

Comment: Try using `type()` to determine if the elements are really a float. https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#module-types

Comment: @ρss how would that help? The `type` is already known, the OP is trying to convert strings *to* floats.

Comment: Perhaps the csv file comes from a mac and only has \r between lines.  Hence on windows you get one humungous line and so the .strip() has no real effect and also two data lines get the last and first fields joined with a \r between them.  Try open(,'rbU') to use "Universal newlines" on input to counter this.